# Unable to uninstall the Field Collection module

Tags: 8, entities, installation

I want to remove field collection module in Drupal 8 as the module has been deprecated. When I try to uninstall after removing the fields from content type the option to uninstall is greyed out.

I get an error

> field_collection: There is content for the entity type: Field
>   Collection Item. `<a
>   href="/admin/modules/uninstall/entity/field_collection_item">Remove
>   field collection item entities</a>`.

Comment: You need to manually delete all field collections and fields linking to field collections.

Comment: @Sssweat  
1. I removed all fields from the field collection  
2. Deleted the field collection from content type (This deletes the field collection)  
3. Ran cron  
4. Uninstall checkbox is still greyed out

Comment: Are the maybe still in revisions? What happens when you visit the link displayed in the error message?

Comment: @leymannx The link goes to website encountered unexpected error. How do i check field collection revisions

Answer (score 1):

I guess you solved this already, but if somebody else stumbels over this, here my 5 cent on how to get rid of field collection. I encountered the same issue as @nitnac23 and was only able to get it out via direct data base manipulation:

1. definitely make a DB backup this time (might save your website)
2. Remove all field collection fields from your entities
3. run the cron potentially multiple times (this cleanes up the entities - fingers_crossed)
4. it is important, that you no longer have **fields pending deletion** as a reason for not beeing able to dissable fields collection (under `/admin/modules/uninstall/`) - if you still have it, try running the cron again (more infos [here](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection/issues/1400478#comment-12403321))
5. clear the contents of the database tables `field_collection_item` and `field_collection_item_revision` directly in the database
6. uninstall field collections now via `/admin/modules/uninstall/`
7. if you have still `field_deleted_*` tables in your DB, drop them (I had 12 before runing the cron and still 2 after unsintsalling the module)

That should do it hopefully :)